# How to update process template in special team project?

Tags: tfs, tfs-process-template

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change Process Template on an existing Team Project in TFS 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998503/how-do-i-change-process-template-on-an-existing-team-project-in-tfs-2010)

There are multiple solutions for updating a Process Template of new projects in one collection

like: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194914%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

but, how to update a Process Template of created Team project in one collection?

Comment: You cannot update the complete Process Template once you've installed it. But you can update parts of it. So it depends on what kind of changes you want to make. Like updating a workitem definition shouldn't be much of a problem, as long as they stay valid.