# Change TFS Process Template

Tags: tfs, tfs-process-template

I've been looking into change the process template on a Team Project, but still have a few questions.  I'm looking to move from MS Agile v5 to TeamPulse v1.  There are no existing work items that we care about, so no need to move those over, however we *do* want to keep the existing source control history/branches.

With this in mind what is the best method to use?  I am currently looking at using `witadmin` but am also considering TFS Integration Tools (MS or CodePlex versions).  I think these are essentially my only options.

Do I need to worry about mapping existing fields to those in the new template if I don't intend to keep the current items?

Any additional advice would also be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to explicitly change the Process Template, though it is possible to import the new work item type definitions using `witadmin`

I found the following answers helpful in finding a solution:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2999219/509356
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5664531/509356

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any existing workitems I recommend to create a new team project with TeamPulse v1 and migrate only the source with the TFS Integration Tool. The problem with the witadmin solution is that you won't be able to delete the old workitem definitions and that could lead to confusions.