# Change TFS 2013 Process Template

Tags: tfs

I currently have my TFS Team project setup with the Agile process template. I would like to change the template to the SCRUM template. Is it possible to change such templates in TFS 2013? I don't want to have to recreate a new TFS project and would prefer to update the template if this was possible.

I would prefer not to have to move to another TFS project as would mean lost history, work items etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change Process Template on an existing Team Project in TFS 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998503/how-do-i-change-process-template-on-an-existing-team-project-in-tfs-2010)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to switch process templates in TFS after a team project has been created. You have to create a new team project with the scrum template and then migrate.

For source control you could always branch out from a stable version, and keep the old project around. That way you will keep you source history. For work items, the only way to migrate with history is to use the TFS integration platform found on codeplex. But that process is quite cumbersome, so I would advice to export to excel and then import into the new project.

Lastly you could edit the current process template and rename the User Story work item to Product Backlog Item, along with any other changes.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the process once you create a Team Project.  You can learn to use witadmin to change things so they look like a different one, but that isn't a best practice.