# TFS Integration Tools MSF Scrum 1.0 to MSF Agile 5.0 XML Template

Tags: xml, templates, tfs, scrum

First my environment:

I have a TFS2010/VS2010 in a Single Server deployment with AT/DT in the same server with Windows Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 (both non R2).

One of the Project Managers wants to migrate from using the Microsoft Scrum 1.0 Process Template to Microsoft Agile v5.0.

I've found many XML templates for doing the opposite thing (Agile 5 to Scrum 1).

I am no programmer (I'm a sysadmin), and while I've tried composing one from two different XMLs that I found (Conchango 2 to Scrum 1 AND Conchango 2 to Agile 5 from Willy's Cave) I see no way of doing it without losing lots of hours. The team is really busy with their own work to ask them so...

Does anyone have a XML template to migrate using the TFS Integration Tools?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options since TFS doesn't support changing Process Templates after you have already created a team project.  I recently did a similar migration and decided the best way would be to create a new Team Project from an Existing Team Project.

MS has a nice walk-through [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181277%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm gonna research it and share it with the Project Manager to see if that fits into his plan.

Comment: Cool- hope it works out for you.  If you need anything else ping me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes looks like this XML is not available but it should not be hard to build. Please check [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2010/08/18/tfs-integration-tools-platform-the-world-of-tfs-project-template-agile-scrum-migrations-part-3.aspx). It has XML for EMC Scrum 2 to MS Agile 5. That could be your starting point. For MS Scrum fields you can dig into template also look at [this XML](https://gist.github.com/564034#file_scrum_for_team_system_v2_to_visual_studio_scrum1.0.xml). Also check this [SO thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222200/can-we-migrate-to-a-new-tfs-process-template-and-keep-history/9235958#9235958)