# How to convert MSF Agile to Scrum 2.0

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

I have just migrated from TFS 2010 to TFS 2012 RC.

I also updated my team projects to MSF Agile 6 thanks to the built-in upgrade feature but I would like to use the SCRUM template instead of using MSF Agile.

I haven't found a way to achieve this.

Do you have any ideas about how to do this, or am I stuck with MSF Agile process ?

Answer (score 10):

You can fully move from one process template to another.

I have detailed 7 ways to achieve this with all of the pros and cons in a blog post:

- [Upgrading your Process Template in Team Foundation Server](http://nakedalm.com/do-you-know-how-to-upgrade-a-process-template-but-still-keep-your-data-intact/)

Now you, I think are looking at #7 as an in-place move from MSF Agile to the Visual Studio Scrum Template. If you follow the instructions for #7 by renaming Work Items and importing new ones then you should be good. I am doing this for a customer today and I have actioned it a number of times and it works well.

- [Process Template Upgrade #7 – Rename Work Items and Import new ones](http://nakedalm.com/process-template-upgrade-7-overwrite-retaining-history-with-limited-migration/)
- [Configure features in Team Foundation Server](http://nakedalm.com/configure-features-in-team-foundation-server-2013/)

Depending on how you decide to do this there is some data loss. You can't get away with from that whatever you do, but this minimises that loss and allows you to fully move over to the new Process Template. Make sure that you add all of the fields that do not exist in the old template and you may want to then rename those old fields with some tag so that you can find them later...

Here is a clean (and most recent) Agile (whatever version) to Visual Studio 2.0 script. Make sure you read the blog posts as well as they define what you are trying to achieve with each step.

```
SET TP="Mt=yTeamProject"
SET COLLECTION="http://myTFSServer:8080/tfs/myCollection"
SET PTROOT=C:\temp\Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2.0

witadmin listwitd /collection:%COLLECTION% /p:%TP%
witadmin renamewitd /collection:%COLLECTION% /p:%TP% /n:"User Story" /new:"Product Backlog Item"
witadmin renamewitd /collection:%COLLECTION% /p:%TP% /n:"Issue" /new:"Impediment"

witadmin importwitd /collection:%COLLECTION% /p:%TP% /f:"%PTROOT%\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\Bug.xml"
witadmin importwitd /collection:%COLLECTION% /p:%TP% /f:"%PTROOT%\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\CodeReviewRequest.xml"
witadmin importwitd /collection:%COLLECTION% /p:%TP% /f:"%PTROOT%\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\CodeReviewResponse.xml"
witadmin importwitd /collection:%COLLECTION% /p:%TP% /f:"%PTROOT%\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\FeedbackRequest.xml"
witadmin importwitd /collection:%COLLECTION% /p:%TP% /f:"%PTROOT%\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\FeedbackResponse.xml"
witadmin importwitd /collection:%COLLECTION% /p:%TP% /f:"%PTROOT%\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\Impediment.xml"
witadmin importwitd /collection:%COLLECTION% /p:%TP% /f:"%PTROOT%\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\SharedStep.xml"
witadmin importwitd /collection:%COLLECTION% /p:%TP% /f:"%PTROOT%\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\ProductBacklogItem.xml"
witadmin importwitd /collection:%COLLECTION% /p:%TP% /f:"%PTROOT%\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\Task.xml"
witadmin importwitd /collection:%COLLECTION% /p:%TP% /f:"%PTROOT%\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\ProductBacklogItem.xml"
witadmin importwitd /collection:%COLLECTION% /p:%TP% /f:"%PTROOT%\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\TestCase.xml"

witadmin importcategories /collection:%COLLECTION% /p:%TP% /f:"%PTROOT%\WorkItem Tracking\Categories.xml"
witadmin importcommonprocessconfig /collection:%COLLECTION% /p:%TP% /f:"%PTROOT%\WorkItem Tracking\Process\CommonConfiguration.xml"
witadmin importagileprocessconfig /collection:%COLLECTION% /p:%TP% /f:"%PTROOT%\WorkItem Tracking\Process\AgileConfiguration.xml"

tfpt addprojectreports  /collection:%COLLECTION% /teamproject:%TP% /processtemplate:"Visual Studio Scrum 2.0"
```

**This script is used at your own risk and should only be used against a test server until you are satisfied that you have a working process.**

There is also a built in feature in 2012 and 2013 to 'enable the new features' that injects what is needed to make your process template work.

- [Configure features in Team Foundation Server](http://nakedalm.com/configure-features-in-team-foundation-server-2013/)

Answer (score -1):

This is possible with [TFS Integration Toolkit](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/). Please look at this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222200/can-we-migrate-to-a-new-tfs-process-template-and-keep-history/9235958#9235958) for more information.

Comment: The TFS Integration Tools are not really for this purpose and you will have a lot of problems if you use it this way.. Use the Script above.

Comment: @MrHinsh - As always, thanks for your magic script. I agree witadmin will help with renames and importing new artifacts. I'm not clear if it will help with data migration if needed. I've personally used Toolkit for TFS 2008->2010->2012 and found it really useful.

Comment: the question was about upgrading in place.